# Js, passing arguments to a function on event

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to pass arguments to a function i created, but i guess i'm missing something...
Here's what i want to do: on event mouseover, the word and its translation get red. On event mouseout, these two words return black. 
I started from this point - pure JavaScript (no function involved):

```
<span id ="e1" onmouseover="document.getElementById('c1').style.color='red'"
      onmouseout = "document.getElementById('c1').style.color='black'"> House </span>
```

I know i can use "this.style.color" but for my final target it's not useful...
So, i used that approach to create a function. On event, arguments are passed to the function, and it colors the words, identifying them with the "getElementById". I thought it was a good idea and that it would have been:

```
<span id ="e1" onmouseover="color(e1,f1)" onmouseout="uncolor(e1,f1)"> House </span>    

<span id ="f1" onmouseover="color(e1,f1)" onmouseout="uncolor(e1,f1)">  Maison </span>

<!-- The script in js would be: -->

<script>
function color(e, f) {
  document.getElementById("e").style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("f").style.color = "red";   
}
function uncolor(e, f) {
  document.getElementById("e").style.color = "black";    
  document.getElementById("f").style.color = "black";
}
</script>
```

I understand that it's a problem about passing arguments (i tried to pass a single argument to a function containing "alert(arg)" and it did not work). I found something about the fact that the function receives the event itself as an argument, but i don't really know if it's the right direction or what...

Any hint will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Surely you meant `getElementById(e)` without the quotes and `color("e1", "f1")` with them?

Comment: It looks like in your js functions that the getElementById you are using the strings "e" and "f" as opposed to the parameters e and f

Comment: Yes, quotes were the problem, quite embarassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st approach**

You need to make 2 updates.

Update html (**Add quotes around parameters**)

```
<span id ="e1" onmouseover="color('e1','f1')" onmouseout="uncolor('e1','f1')"> House </span>    

<span id ="f1" onmouseover="color('e1','f1')" onmouseout="uncolor('e1','f1')">  Maison </span>
```

Update your script (**Remove quotes when using in function**)

```
<script>
function color(e, f) {
  document.getElementById(e).style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById(f).style.color = "red";   
}
function uncolor(e, f) {
  document.getElementById(e).style.color = "black";    
  document.getElementById(f).style.color = "black";
}
</script>
```

**2nd approach**

No html update. Update your script to following

```
<script>
function color(e, f) {
  e.style.color = "red";
  f.style.color = "red";   
}
function uncolor(e, f) {
  e.style.color = "black";    
  f.style.color = "black";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using (this) it's more simple .

**Updated Code**

```
<span id ="e1" onmouseover="color(this)" onmouseout="uncolor(this)"> House </span>

<span id ="f1" onmouseover="color(this)" onmouseout="uncolor(this)">  Maison </span>
```

By Using "this" you pass the full control to function.

```
  function color(control) {
  control.style.color = "red";
  control.style.color = "red";   
  }

 function uncolor(control) {
  control.style.color = "black";    
  control.style.color = "black";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing the point, but this should all be done in CSS if at all possible.  You can use the adjacent sibling selector `+` or general sibling selector `~` to get the translation that appears after the word.  However, there's no widely supported way to go from the translation to a previous sibling.  The easiest way to overcome that is to put both elements inside another container.

Simplified HTML:

```
<div class="word-pair">
    <span id ="e1" class="word"> House </span>    
    <span id ="f1" class="translation">  Maison </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.word-pair span{
    color:#000;
    transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
}
div.word-pair:hover span {
    color:red;
}
```

Fiddle Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/kw7wyux4/

Comment: The fact is that i wanted to use a function because i would use it to write english text with french translation.